# Outputting lists input-ready as in datapasta::dpasta

Tags: r, list, vector, output

I am trying to keep my scripts organised, and recently found this really useful function dpasta() from datapasta package. It works as shown below:

```
library(datapasta)
df<-data.frame(A=seq(1,4), B=rep(NA,4))
dpasta(df)
>data.frame(
           A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
           B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

However, I have many complex lists I'd like to output in a similar way, but dpasta won't work on lists. Could anyone suggest a function that would do a similar job with such a list?

```
  L<-list(A=rep(0,1), rep(NA,2), rep(NA,32), B=c(1,100,45))
```

Comment: What is the 1, 100, 45

Comment: @akrun just random numbers. It is just some example.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Does `dput(L)` or `dump("L","")` not work for you? Do you need it to look "pretty" or use some particular formatting?

Comment: @MrFlick I'd like it to output in some input-ready format like dpasta() accomplishes with data.frames. dput() is OK but is a bit messy for records.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand exactly what that means. What exactly are the requirements. What do the built in function `dput()` and `dump()` not do that you need such a function to do?

Comment: @MrFlick Exactly the same that "the built in function dput() and dump() will not do", but datapasta::dpasta() will, but unfortunately only for dataframes. I cannot build a dpasta() that works on lists.

Answer (score 1):

While I think @MrFlick's solutions of `dput(L)` and/or `dump("L", "")` are the best solutions here, if you are set on the `dpasta` solution, the help page suggests:

> `input`    a vector, data.frame, or tibble

So we could just change your list to a tibble:

```
tibble_list <- tibble::tibble(L)

dpasta(tibble_list)
```

```
>tibble::tribble(
                                                                                                                                 ~L,
                                                                                                                                  0,
                                                                                                                          c(NA, NA),
  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                                                                                                                      c(1, 100, 45)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks ! Not perfect but already better than I had before. I didn't know tibble format yet...